# javascript addEventListener no funciona

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy aprendiendo javascript, y no logro conseguir que mis elementos llamen a su función cuando son clickeados, ni el submit del form, ni los enlaces log in y sign in. No se por que. Lo que intento hacer es que en un  tengo un , al igual que con dos enlaces cada uno con su propio id. Luego con javascript, creo tres variables, una para cada elemento, y les asigno su valor con document.getElementById('id del elemento'), y les agrego un event listener, con addEventListener('click', submit()); en el caso del boton de submit, pero cuando hago click en submit, no realiza la funcion que le asigno.
Les adjunto el html y el javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta viewport="width=device-width" <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="jesus diaz, diseño web, software developer">
    <meta name="author" content="Jesus Diaz">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <!-- width=device-width : establecemos que el ancho de la página sea igual al del dispositivo
         user-scalable=no   : establecemos que el usuario no puede escalar el sitio web
         initial-scale=1.0  : establecemos que la página tendrá un tamaño inicial de 1
         maximum-scale=1.0  : establecemos que la página tendrá un tamaño maximo de 1
         minimum-scale=1.0  : establecemos que la página tendrá un tamaño mínimo de 1 -->
    <title>Log In/Sign In</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/styles.css">
    <script src="../javascript/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="main">
        <form class="main__form">
            <input type="text" class="input" id="main__form--input--usuario" placeholder="Usuario" required>
            <input type="password" class="input" id="main__form--input--password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input type="submit" class="boton" id="main__form--submit" value="Aceptar">
        </form>
        <div class="main__opciones">
            <a href="" class="enlace" id="main__opciones--signIn">Sign In</a>
            <a href="" class="enlace" id="main__opciones--logIn">Log In</a>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

```
function submit() {
    let usuario = document.getElementById('main__form--input--usuario').value;
    let password = document.getElementById('main__form--input--password').value;
    alert('Usuario: ' + usuario + '\nPassword: ' + password);
}

function logIn() {
    alert('Log In');
}

function signIn() {
    alert('Sign In');
}

var botonSubmit = document.getElementById('main__form--submit');
var enlaceSigIn = document.getElementById('main__opciones--signIn');
var enlaceLogIn = document.getElementById('main__opciones--logIn');

botonSubmit.addEventListener('click', submit());
enlaceLogIn.addEventListener('click', logIn());
enlaceSignIn.addEventListener('click', signIn());
```

Comment: La etiqueta script la estás agregando antes de tu body, como el archivo se va a leer de arriba hacia abajo primero carga tu script antes que el body y por tanto no encuentra el elemento al cual agregar el eventListener.

La primera solución es poner el archivo JS abajo de body, la segunda opción es poner un eventListener window.onload y adentro cargar los demás eventos

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas poner la función sin los paréntesis cuando asignas el listener, [como se explica en la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Por otra parte, considera otorgar a cada función el parámetro del evento `e`, para poder usar luego [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), de lo contrario, la página se recargará cada vez que hagas click en alguno de los elementos.

Por último, se recomienda poner todo el código que trabaja con elementos del DOM dentro de un listener [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) el cual escucha que el DOM esté listo, así no se intentará usar ningún elemento hasta que el DOM no esté cargado.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

  function submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let usuario = document.getElementById('main__form--input--usuario').value;
    let password = document.getElementById('main__form--input--password').value;
    alert('Usuario: ' + usuario + '\nPassword: ' + password);
  }

  function logIn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Log In');
  }

  function signIn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Sign In');
  }

  var botonSubmit = document.getElementById('main__form--submit');
  var enlaceSignIn = document.getElementById('main__opciones--signIn');
  var enlaceLogIn = document.getElementById('main__opciones--logIn');

  botonSubmit.addEventListener('click', submit);
  enlaceLogIn.addEventListener('click', logIn);
  enlaceSignIn.addEventListener('click', signIn);
  
});
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <form class="main__form">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="main__form--input--usuario" placeholder="Usuario" required>
    <input type="password" class="input" id="main__form--input--password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="submit" class="boton" id="main__form--submit" value="Aceptar">
  </form>
  <div class="main__opciones">
    <a href="" class="enlace" id="main__opciones--signIn">Sign In</a>
    <a href="" class="enlace" id="main__opciones--logIn">Log In</a>
  </div>
</section>
```